# Apache Maven Resources Plugin exclude a directory

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I'm trying to copy some resources from one point to an other during the build process. Therefore I use the Apache Maven Resources Plugin. Actually I exclude some files, I don't need. But I want also to exclude a directory. I tried serveral ways but it didn't work.

```
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-client-product</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/pro/client</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>target\products\client\win32\win32\x86\</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>p2</exclude>
                        <exclude>eclipsec.exe</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

In this example I tried to exclude the folder "p2".

```
<exclude>*/p2/**</exclude>
<exclude>p2/**</exclude>
<exclude>**/p2</exclude>
```

Also don't work.

Comment: Ever tried to use `<exclude>**/p2/**</exclude>` ?

Comment: BTW: Why are you using the `verify` phase?

Comment: BTW: Why are you using the `verify` phase?

Comment: It's an old configuration, don't know why I did this ^^ Your suggestion is working thanks! Pls post it as Answer, so I can mark it as right.

Comment: @khmarbaise we use verify to prevent installing maven the artifacts to the local m2 repository. Therefore we have a separate build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<exclude>**/p2/**</exclude>`

is the correct answer thanks to @khmarbaise.

Comment: Someone trying to farm reputation with the knowledge of others?

Comment: @UweAllner: The answer was in the comments and I just added it, and tagged the source.

Comment: You did not add anything of value; not an explanation, additional information or whatever.

Comment: this works but what if you want to exclude only a specific p2 directory not all p2 directories?

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer.  This Documentation doesn't really give much detail:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-war-plugin-2.3/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<resource>
  <directory>p2</directory>
  <excludes>
      <exclude>p2/**</exclude>
   </excludes>
 </resource>
```